# Including a dist file inside an app that contains a different version of angular

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, duplicates, bundle, webpack

Let's say we have an app called "App1" that uses Angular 1.4 and webpack. Then we have "App2" which is based on webpack and Angular 1.5. We create the bundle of App2 using webpack and using bower we install it on App1.

So when creating the bundle for App1, is webpack going to include the entire Angular 1.4 and 1.5 in it?

Answer (score 0):

webpack does not manage versions of libraries. You just say i.e. import angular, where angular is in bower_components.

In your scenario you will face errors/warnings when you install angular 1.5 and module which requires angular 1.4 with bower.

Comment: True. I understand if you're using Angular 1.5 and some of the dependent modules require 1.4, you will get errors and warnings. I'm assuming App2 only contains libraries that are compatible with Angular 1.5. Hence, the bundle that is created for App2 will be without warnings or errors. However, I'm not too sure if I install App2 bundle through bower in App1, the final bundle will contain Angular 1.5 and Angular 1.4 at the same time under different name spaces?